# DFT but using non-sinusoidal periodic waveforms.

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing, wavelets

Is there an established way of decomposing a discrete periodic (complex) signal into a sum of non-sinusoidal periodic waveforms (eg square, triangle, and sawtooth)?

For my use case the input waveform is periodic, but as I understand that's a condition which always holds for DFT even if it's easy to work around it in practical applications.

Comment: Why do you need it. Things get more interesting when decomposing a periodic function (the möbius function appears).

Comment: I want to generate looping 1/f noise (pink noise) sequences but with recognizable characteristics of other waveforms than sines.
Come to think of it, approximating the (random) input isn't really important. Maybe I don't need to do decomposition. I could just generate random components and compose a sequence from there.

Comment: Also I've looked the möbius function and can't see how it relates.

Comment: A $1$-periodic odd (smooth) function is equal to its Fourier series which is $f(x)=\sum_{n\ge 1} b_n \sin(2\pi nx)$, then $\sin(2\pi x) = -\pi \sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{\mu(k)}{k} saw(kx)$ gives $f(x) = -\pi\sum_{m\ge 1} saw(mx) \sum_{k | m} \frac{\mu(k)}{k} b_{m/k}$ where $saw(x)=x-\lfloor x\rfloor -1/2$. I didn't understand what you are willing to do, can you be more explicit.

Comment: Sure. The Walsh-Hadamard transform is one example, the Harr transform is another. When you "decompose", all you are doing is changing the basis. I've never seen a saw-tooth basis, but that doesn't mean you couldn't come up with one. Bases do not even have to be orthogonal, though that is generally preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at using B-splines? The 0th-order B-spline is a simple pulse, 1st-order (convolution of 2 0th order B-splines) is a triangle, and they keep going up from there...[image: order 0][image: order 1][image: order 2][image: order 3]

For whatever transform you want to use/develop, arguably one of the most basic requirements is that they possess the *partition of unity* property (see [Jawerth and Sweldens (1993)](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.45.5864&rep=rep1&type=pdf))—otherwise, it would be difficult to manage even approximating a constant function well. All B-splines have *partition of unity* property.[image: order 0][image: order 1][image]

B-splines also have a nice connection to the Daubechies wavelets: each p-order Daubechies scaling function has a p-order B-spline component that show up as p zeroes in the complex z-plane.[image: D8]

Answer (score 0):

If you are after a random basis and you know some statistical properties of the target family of waveforms, have you looked into using a Karhunen-Loève Expansion (KL-Expansion)? In a KL-Expansion, the set of eigen-vectors of the auto-correlation operator of the signal x(t) is a basis (demonstrates *convergence in probability*) for x(t).

In the discrete x(n) case, you can calculate a quasi-basis using an auto-correlation matrix of x(n) and *Cholesky Decomposition*.
See [Clarkson (1993) *Optimal and Adaptive Signal Processing* page 131](https://books.google.com/books?vid=ISBN0849386098&pg=PA131)